# Why does yearmonth return something different if I type in a date?

Tags: r, tsibble, yearmonth

I want to create a yearmonth of "2016 Jan" and am using tsibble. For some reason when I create the yearmonth object I get back the month prior. Here's an example:

```r
> yearmonth("2016 Jan")
<yearmonth[1]>
[1] "2015 Dec"
> yearmonth("2016 Feb")
<yearmonth[1]>
[1] "2016 Jan"
```

I'm confused because if I use `make_yearmonth` I get what I'm expecting and can use `yearmonth` to  verify:

```r
> ym <- make_yearmonth(year=2016, month=1)
> ym
<yearmonth[1]>
[1] "2016 Jan"
> yearmonth(ym)
<yearmonth[1]>
[1] "2016 Jan"
```

So why does `yearmonth` return something different if I type a date, e.g. "2016 Jan", compared to using `make_yearmonth`?

Comment: If I do: `library(tsibble)   yearmonth("2016 Jan")` , I get [1] "2016 Jan".

Comment: Could be a timezone or locale issue - could you provide a reprex including your session info? `reprex::reprex(si = TRUE)`.